# Is Self-Signed IdentityServer4 signing credential good enough in production?

Tags: certificate, identityserver4, signing

We are using IdentityServer4 and our version loads the signing key from a PFX file in file system or from the windows certificate store. Using the certificate works. The question is - which certificate issuer should be used in production?

Is a certificate from a public CA recommended? Or is it enough to have a self-signed certificate (without a CA at all) such as it can be created with IIS Manager?

In our tests we have found that the client could still validate the signature in the access token, even if the signing certificate would not have a valid CA chain on the client.

In the docs, it says that you can also use raw key material instead of a certificate:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/crypto.html#token-signing-and-validation
In this scenario there would be no CA chain whatsoever.

That leads me to the assumption, that when the client loads the public signing key (via the HTTP(s) endpoint), the CA chain information might not be passed anyways. Is that right? Through the loading mechanism via HTTPs you also have a combined security mechanism.

So my conclusion is that for the signing credential a self-signed cert is just as safe as one from VeriSign. Can this be confirmed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no certificate involved in signing and verifying the tokens. Only a private and public key (RSA or ECDSA key).

However a certificate can be useful to "import/transport" the keys into .NET. So, because of that we don't care about who issued the certificate.

When importing the key, one approach is to bundle the certificate that holds the public key + the private key and store it in a PKCE#12 file (.pfx/.p12 extension). Then load that file into .NET. Before .NET 5 working with keys was a bit hard.

The more important thing is that you can manage and deploy the private key in a secure way and that it is persisted over time.

Optionally, you can add support for key-rotation.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable? or do you want me to improve it further?

Comment: Can you suggest how to achieve key rotation when using X.509 certificates

Comment: In  IdentityServer there is now a built in key rotation system.  see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/keys/

Comment: I am using IS4, free version. Is there a way to implement the same in IS4

Comment: It all depends where you store your certificates. One option is to use Azure Key vault,  see https://duckduckgo.com/?q=azure+key+vault+key+rotation&ia=web

Comment: Certificate is stored on windows certificate store, under Trusted Root Certificate Authorities

Comment: it can perhaps be easier to host all certificates in a central store, either in your company or externally (like Azure Key Vault).

Comment: I will consider that option. Thanks.